# Elm/html: ordered list of different kind of elements

Tags: elm

I was looking at some Elm examples and I found ["Example 3: A Dynamic List of Counters"](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/#example-3-a-dynamic-list-of-counters). I wanted to alter it to include checkboxes, so a single list with counters and/or checkboxes. Each having their own actions and model (such as a name, and a checked bool).

On top of that I would like to order the list, so that checked checkboxes all appear at the top, unchecked at the bottom and the counters in the middle.

I couldn't find any examples on how to do and structure this though.

Note: I'm very new to Elm (and functional programming in general).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use a union type for the item (untested, I don't have a Elm environment right now to check this):

```
type Item = Checkbox String Bool | Counter

type alias Model =
    { items : List ( ID, Item )
    , nextID : ID
    }
```

Depending on the type of item, you'd then render it as

```
viewItem item =
   case item of
     Counter value -> renderCounter value
     CheckBox name state -> renderCheckbox name state
```

All your view has to do is call viewItem for each Item, sort the items and put everything in a container (e.g. a div):

```
view address model =
  let 
    items = List.map (viewItem address) model.items 
            |> List.sort (your custom sorting here)
  in
      div [] ([remove, insert] ++ items)
```